# DataGridView BindingList Combobox values

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Ситуация такая. есть класс у которого есть свойство другой класс

```
public class test1
{
    private test2 _t2;
    public test2 t2 { get { return _t2; } set { _t2 = value; } }
    public test1(test2 t2)
    {
        this.t2 = t2;
    }
    public test1() : this(new test2()) { }
}

public class test2
{
    private string _s;
    public string s { get { return _s; } set { _s = value; } }

    public test2(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public test2() : this("none") { }
}
```

Есть на форме

```
private BindingList<test1> bl = new BindingList<test1>();
    public static test2[] values = { new test2("none"), new test2("one"), new test2("two") };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DGV1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        DGV1.AutoSize = true;
        DGV1.DataSource = bl;
        DGV1.Columns.AddRange(getColumn());
    }
    private DataGridViewColumn getColumn()
    {
        DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();

        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        combo.DataSource = values;
        combo.DataPropertyName = "t2";
        combo.Name = "t2";
        column = combo;
        return column;
    }
```

Хочу выводить в комбобокс значения из списка (values). Надеюсь, что при выборе одного происходит присвение данного объекта `test2` полю в `test1.t2`, но этого не происходит. У меня создается впечатление, что все просто, но ни как не дотумкать, как же верно сделать.

Comment: Я, кажется, понимаю, что вам нужно. Однако, для этого нужно каким-то образом связать значения в двух коллекциях. Это можно сделать через первичный и внешний ключ, сделав две таблицы DataTable в DataSet'е. Могу привести пример такого решения. В-общем, опишите, подробней, какую реальную задачу решаете.

Comment: в реальности у меня есть класс характеристик объекта, где есть так скажем праймари кей - имя набора характеристик. а в датавьюгриде я хочу создавать "слой" некоторой толщины и соответственно поле скажем double и сопоставлять ему некоторые характеристики - согласно имени(PK)
для чего у меня есть спец класс где есть поле double толщина; и myType характеристики; вот именно BindingList этого класса я отправляю DataSorc-ом в DGV...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1**

В класс `test2` добавьте свойство `Value`:

```
public class test2
{
    public string s { get; set; }

    public test2 Value {
        get { return this; }
    }

    public test2(string s = "none")
    {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

И изменить метод `getColumn`:

```
private DataGridViewColumn getColumn()
{
    var combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    combo.DataSource = values;
    combo.DataPropertyName = "t2";
    combo.DisplayMember = "s";
    combo.ValueMember = "Value";
    return combo;
}
```

**Вариант 2**

Классы не трогаем. Изменяем метод `getColumn`:

```
private DataGridViewColumn getColumn()
{
    var combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx();
    combo.DataSource = values;
    combo.DataPropertyName = "t2";
    combo.DisplayMember = "s";
    return combo;
}
```

Реализация класса `DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx`:

```
public sealed class DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx : DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    public DataGridViewComboBoxColumnEx()
    {
        CellTemplate = new DataGridViewComboBoxCellEx();
    }
}

public class DataGridViewComboBoxCellEx : DataGridViewComboBoxCell
{
    private PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor;

    private CurrencyManager CurrencyManager
    {
        get
        {
            var bindingMemberInfo = new BindingMemberInfo(DisplayMember);
            if (DataGridView != null)
            {
                return (CurrencyManager) DataGridView.BindingContext[DataSource, bindingMemberInfo.BindingPath];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private PropertyDescriptor PropertyDescriptor
    {
        get
        {
            return propertyDescriptor ?? (propertyDescriptor = CurrencyManager.GetItemProperties().Find(DisplayMember, true));
        }
    }

    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex,
        ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter valueTypeConverter,
        TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        if (value == null || value == cellStyle.DataSourceNullValue)
            return "";

        return base.GetFormattedValue(PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(value),
            rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter,
            formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
    }

    public override object ParseFormattedValue(object formattedValue,
        DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter,
        TypeConverter valueTypeConverter)
    {
        foreach (var item in CurrencyManager.List)
        {
            if ((string)PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(item) == (string)formattedValue)
                return item;
        }

        return base.ParseFormattedValue(formattedValue, cellStyle,
            formattedValueTypeConverter, valueTypeConverter);
    }
}
```

Comment: не добавить новый элемент.. то есть если например я создаю колонки по вышеуказанному и затем добавляю в BindingList скажем пару экземпляров t1(values[0]) t1(values[2]) ... то все ок и я могу менять в BindingList значение поля t2 у обоих экземпляров,... но я не могу создать новый экземпляр.. то етсь не могу добавить строку говорит недопустимое значение

Comment: А как вы создаете новый экземпляр, который не добавляется? А сообщение об ошибке оригинальное какое? В первом или втором варианте возникает проблема?

Comment: да, извините, мало дал информации)) первый вариант - для второго мне еще почитать много надо. 
если Я создаю новый экземпляр test1 в bindingList таким образом:
bl.Add(new test1(values[0]));
bl.Add(new test1(values[1]));
то только их я соответственно и вижу в датагрид, но если попытаться создать новую строку... ошибка 
Недопустимое значение datagridviewcomboboxcell

хотя наверное можно обработать исключение и попробовать посмотреть стек? щас попробую

Comment: ага там надо DataEror обработать

Comment: Полный код запустите http://pastebin.com/YSkj9JmM

Comment: охереть... простите,. все работает ))) буду изучать где я лоханулся. спасибо!

Comment: ошибка была в конструкторе по умолчанию для test1
надо было как у вас а у меня было
public test1():this(new test2()) { }